# Storing Secondary Data Based on Primary Selection

Tags: mysql

Generically, I'm wondering how I would store secondary data based on the type of primary data.

Here's the real-world situation.  When adding "students" to my database, I want to start their referral.  This will be done by referencing a table called "referrer" that stores a list of options that will appear in a drop-down box, as such:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| referrer_id | referrer      |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 |       Student |
|           2 | Search Engine |
|           3 |            Ad |
+-------------+---------------+
```

So in the student's table, I'll store the referrer_id -- Easy enough.

Based on the selection, I'd like the user to be able to enter secondary information.  For instance, if they choose "Student" from the list, a second drop-down box will appear presenting them with a list of existing students so they can specify which student was the referrer, and I would want to store the student_id.  If they chose either "Search Engine", I would present them with a text box where they can enter the name of the search engine, and I would store that text.

So my question is, how should me "students" table be structured in order to hold this information, since sometimes I'll be storing a student_id, or the text entered in a box, or... ?  My initial thought is to create additional columns in the students table to hold the various possibilities, but that seems both messy and not scalable, so I don't care for it.  I'm wondering if an additional cross-reference table would be warranted here, that would hold the student_id, the referrer_id, and then a value (such as the referring student_id, or the value entered into the text box).  Or perhaps instead of "value", I could have "value_id", "value_text", and so on for different data type possibilities.  The value of referrer_id in this table would tell me which column contains the data I want.  While this seems cleaner than expanding out the students table, it does still seem a bit messy.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps in the referrer table you have an additional parameters columns that denote the parameters a particular referrer you have (for students, parameter_1 column might be Student Name). Then, when it's time to serialize these parameters when adding into the students table you can serialize the type and it's parameters with a simple array-join. (so if maybe if you picked student and the student John Doe, referrer for this student could be 1|John Doe|)

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, wouldn't serializing make it difficult to use the values in a WHERE clause to retrieve, say, all of the students that have a particular referral_id?

Comment: Please don't. Storing non-scalar data in a column breaks the first normal form. Less formally, it is defeating a fundamental purpose of a relational database.